# Mail from Outlook Web App's SMTP

Tags: email, wordpress

I'm using WP-Mail-SMTP (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp).

I want to use this plugin (or another plugin) to send mail from Outlook Web App's SMTP.

I used these setting:

> **From Email:** noreply@xxx.xx
>
> **From Name:** Noreply
>
> **Mailer:** Send all WordPress emails via SMTP.
>
> **SMTP Host:** pod51002.outlook.com
>
> **SMTP Port:** 587
>
> **Authentication:** Use TLS encryption.
>
> **Username:** xxx@xxx.xx
>
> **Password:** xxx

When I send a test email I recieve this error:

```
Test Message Sent

The result was:
bool(false)

The full debugging output is shown below:
object(PHPMailer)#6049 (45) {
   ...long list...
}

The SMTP debugging output is shown below:
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: No route to host (113)
```

What am I doing wrong???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem sounds like your host is blocking the outgoing port.  If you have access to the shell or ssh command line you can test the connection to the mail server using telnet.

```
 telnet pod51002.outlook.com 587
```

It should return something like this: (use control ] to quit after you connect)

```
x-wing-$: telnet pod51002.outlook.com 587
Trying 157.55.9.147...
Connected to pod51002.outlook.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 pod51002.outlook.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 29 Mar 2011 09:58:16 +0000
^]
telnet> quit
Connection closed.
```

If it fails then you need to contact your host to have them open up the port.

Comment: I have send the question to my hosting provider.

Comment: I have contacted my hosting provider. They indeed block port number 587. I think that I can't work with this mailhost on my website.

Comment: They wont open it up for you?  I had the same problem with my VPS and my host opened the port for me.